# Run Hudson as Windows Service on different port

Tags: windows, service, hudson, port

I am running Hudson as a windows service on windows 7.  I did this by downloading the latest version as a war file from http://hudson-ci.org/download/war/.  I put the war file in C:\Build\Hudson, and then started it by entering the command "C:\Build\Hudson> java -jar hudson.war" in cmd (see [here](http://www.eclipse.org/hudson/the-hudson-book/book-hudson.chunked/ch02.html)).

After I finished installing plugins I went to "Manage Hudson" and clicked "Install as Windows Service".  You can see the step-by-step instructions for what I did here: http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Installing+Hudson+as+a+Windows+service.  It is now running on port 8080.  I want to change it to run on port 19091.  After Googling and searching Stack Overflow for an answer, it seems that the standard way to do this is to change the setting in Hudson.xml, which is located in the Hudson installation directory (see [here](http://fuzz-box.blogspot.com/2011/03/change-hudson-jenkins-default-port.html) for an example answer).

Here's the Problem:  For me there is no installation directory, because I downloaded Hudson as a war file.  So my question is this: Is there any way to change the port Hudson runs on as a service without starting over, or do I need to go about this whole process differently (and if so, what is the best way)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I was wrong about not having an installation directory.  The answer is indeed to go to the installation directory, you will still have one even if you downloaded Hudson as a war file.
The directory to hudson.xml is HUDSON_HOME.hudson\hudson.xml.
In`<service><arguments>...</arguments></service>` change `--httpPort=8080` to `--httpPort=19091`.
The reason I had trouble before was that I couldn't see any folders that started with a "`.`" (I'm not sure why that was).